# How do I save multiple fields for an associated model in cakePHP?

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I have the following in my form for saving borrowed items in the database:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('BorrowedItem.0.item_type'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('BorrowedItem.0.manufacturer'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('BorrowedItem.0.collection'); ?>
```

I have used the following to save the records in the database and this works fine - borrowed items are inserted.

```
function admin_create(){
    $this->BorrowedRecord->saveAll($this->data);
    $this->redirect('/admin/');
}
```

The relationship I have defined is:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Invoice Model
 *
 */
class BorrowedRecord extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'BorrowedRecord';
    public $hasMany = 'BorrowedItem';
}
```

Is it possible to save multiple records without specifying the '0' in the form helper? I need to dynamically create inputs using javascript so there could be one or possibly 5 borrowed items per borrowed record. Therefore it could be difficult/cumbersome to attempt to specify the x number for the field input.

I feel as though I'm missing the correct way to do this.

Comment: See how look your fields, and create same in js with increment keys. example from blueimp upload with cakephp ```<input class="position" type="text" name="data[Image][{%=file.id%}][position]" id="ImagePosition" value="{%=file.position%}" size="1" > ```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I think you missed the model name in your code please edit it as bellow.

```
function admin_create(){
    $this->BorrowedRecord->saveAll($this->request->data['BorrowedRecord']);
    $this->redirect('/admin/');
}
```